# Import csv files into a new database each

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am supposed to create a database in Access that will later be transferred to Oracle. For each year I am supposed to import a csv file that contains millions of rows of data, dating back to 1985. I believe Access cannot hold all this data so I thought I would have a main database reference other databases.

What code do I need to create a database for each year?

This is what I have so far:

```
DocLocate = InputBox("Input Document Location") & "\"
StartYear = InputBox("Input Start Year")
EndYear = InputBox("Input End Year")
i = StartYear

strPath = DocLocate

strTable = strFile

strFile = "mar31_wts_" & i & ".csv"
Do Until i > EndYear
    strPathFile = strPath & strFile
    DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, acSpreadsheetTypeText, strFile, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames
    i = i + 1
    strFile = "mar31_wts_" & i & ".csv"
Loop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to import csv data into Access databases. Using the `DoCmd.TransferText` method you will import into the current database of the application where the code is executed.

If you want to import into another database than the one that executes your VBA code, you'll have to create another `Application` object and open the destination database in there:

```
Dim app As Application
Dim strDBPath As String

' create the database
strDBPath = "<path_to_db>\db.accdb"
DAO.CreateDatabase(strDBPath, dbLangGeneral).Close

' open the database in a new Access Application
Set app = New Application
app.OpenCurrentDatabase strDBPath

' import the csv file into that database
app.DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, acSpreadsheetTypeText, strFile, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames

' close the database and the Access application
app.Quit acQuitSaveNone
```

If you want to use an import specification, that must be present in the newly created database. In that case it would probably be better to manually create an empty template database already containing what you need (the specification for example) and in the code above, instead of creating a new one with `DAO.CreateDatabase`, create of copy of the template database.

If you want all those imported tables in the various new databases linked in your main database, you can call this:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, , strDBPath, acTable, strFile, strFile
```

Comment: What is the best way to iterate so each year creates a new database. I did: 'Do Until i > EndYear'

Comment: Also Where would the best place to put the link line?

Comment: Needs to be after the data was imported, Would probably be best at the very end, after `app.Quit`

Comment: Inside the iteration? What is the best way to iterate from start year to end year? I used: Do Until i > EndYear

Comment: If yoy want to create the link for each file that was imported during the loop, you better put the code that creates the links in the loop as well! There are several ways to create a loop, the best one for your case would be a `For` loop, as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251601.aspx

Comment: There are 2 documents i want on the main database keep returning conversion error, where one column is mostly numbers with a few that say "90+" , how do you resolve this error to make all the column not a number but a string I guess?

Comment: You should probably ask this in another question, it seems unrelated to the current question of how to create a separate database for each imported file. If my answer worked for that, you should upvote it and mark is as the accepted answer by clicking the check mark beneath the vote buttons; it will generate reputation points for both of us. If you still have troubles with the import of a certain csv file, just ask this in another question.